# c# How do I write to a .resx file?

Tags: c#

I found this example of how to read from .resx file

```
    public static void ReadResourceFile()
    {
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("XmlReadAndWritePractice.Resource1", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        //String strWebsite = rm.GetString("Website",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);   
        String strName = rm.GetString("FirstName");
        Console.WriteLine(strName);

    }
```

But how do I edit or add to .resx file? I found the following example but it's not what I'm expecting.

```
    private static void CreateResourceFile()
    {
        // Creates a resource writer.
        IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter("c:\\temp\\Resource1.resx");

        // Adds resources to the resource writer.
        writer.AddResource("String 1", "First String");

        writer.AddResource("String 2", "Second String");

        writer.AddResource("String 3", "Third String");

        // Writes the resources to the file or stream, and closes it.
        writer.Close();

    }
```

[image]

**Resource References**

[ResourceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ResourceWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051558/c-sharp-how-do-i-write-to-a-resx-file should help

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are generating the binary of the resx file.

Have you tried this?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to call generate before the close.

```
writer.Generate();
writer.Close();
```

Comment: `Close` already saves resources - so no need to call `Generate`, but more importantly this suggestion not even tries to answer OP's problem with getting binary version of resource (.resource format) when they looking for text output(.resx).

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void CreateResourceFile()
{
    using (ResXResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter("c:\\temp\\Resource1.resx"))
    {
        writer.AddResource("String 1", "First String");
        writer.AddResource("String 2", "Second String");
        writer.AddResource("String 3", "Third String");
        writer.Generate();
    }
}
```

Comment: So apparently my issue was I was doing this in a Console application. As soon as I tried with Windows Forms application it worked perfect. Any insights?

Comment: It could have something to do with ResXResourceWriter being part of the winforms assembly. You can get them packaged separately with [ResXResourceReader.NetStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ResXResourceReader.NetStandard)